# Method onCreate() is not call

Tags: android, mosby

app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

dependencies {
...
implementation 'com.hannesdorfmann.mosby3:mvi:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.hannesdorfmann.mosby3:mvp:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.hannesdorfmann.mosby3:viewstate:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.hannesdorfmann.mosby3:mvp-lce:3.1.0'

}
```

Here my activity:

```
import com.hannesdorfmann.mosby3.mvp.MvpActivity;
    public class OfferDetailsPdfActivity extends MvpActivity<OfferDetailsPdfMvp.View, OfferDetailsPdfPresenterImplMvp> implements OnPageChangeListener, OfferDetailsPdfMvp.View {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    }
```

And method `onCreate()` on my activity **OfferDetailsPdfActivity**  was success call.

But I need to pass param to activity, so here production code:

```
public class OfferDetailsPdfActivity extends MvpActivity<OfferDetailsPdfMvp.View, OfferDetailsPdfPresenterImplMvp> implements OnPageChangeListener, OfferDetailsPdfMvp.View {
private OfferDetailsPdfPresenterImplMvp presenter;
    private int offerId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        Debug.d(TAG, "onCreate: extras = " + AndroidUtil.bundle2String(extras)
                + "\nsavedInstanceState = " + AndroidUtil.bundle2String(savedInstanceState)
        );
        if (extras != null) {
            offerId = extras.getInt(Offer.ID);
        }
            setContentView(R.layout.offer_details_pdf);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public OfferDetailsPdfPresenterImplMvp createPresenter() {
        Debug.d(TAG, "createPresenter: offerId = " + offerId);
        presenter = new OfferDetailsPdfPresenterImplMvp(this, offerId);
        return presenter;
    }
```

And now in my activity method `onCreate()` is not call, but method `createPresenter()` was success called. Has text ***"createPresenter: offerId = 0"***

As you can see from logcat the method `onCreate()` was not called. In logcat no text "***onCreate: extras...***"

Why?

Here logcat:

```
D/com.myproject.android.customer.ui.OfferDetailsPdfActivity(  946): createPresenter: offerId = 0
        Process: com.myproject.android.customer.debug, PID: 30127
       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myproject.android.customer.debug/com.myproject.android.customer.ui.OfferDetailsPdfActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null objects cannot be copied from Realm.
           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null objects cannot be copied from Realm.
           at io.realm.Realm.checkValidObjectForDetach(Realm.java:1625)
           at io.realm.Realm.copyFromRealm(Realm.java:1318)
           at io.realm.Realm.copyFromRealm(Realm.java:1292)
           at com.myproject.android.customer.service.OfferService.getOffer(OfferService.java:54)
           at com.myproject.android.customer.mvp.presenter.OfferDetailsPdfPresenterImplMvp.loadData(OfferDetailsPdfPresenterImplMvp.java:64)
           at com.myproject.android.customer.mvp.presenter.OfferDetailsPdfPresenterImplMvp.<init>(OfferDetailsPdfPresenterImplMvp.java:59)
           at com.myproject.android.customer.ui.OfferDetailsPdfActivity.createPresenter(OfferDetailsPdfActivity.java:76)
           at com.myproject.android.customer.ui.OfferDetailsPdfActivity.createPresenter(OfferDetailsPdfActivity.java:35)
           at com.hannesdorfmann.mosby3.mvp.delegate.ActivityMvpDelegateImpl.createViewIdAndCreatePresenter(ActivityMvpDelegateImpl.java:90)
           at com.hannesdorfmann.mosby3.mvp.delegate.ActivityMvpDelegateImpl.onCreate(ActivityMvpDelegateImpl.java:142)
           at com.hannesdorfmann.mosby3.mvp.MvpActivity.onCreate(MvpActivity.java:42)
           at com.myproject.android.customer.ui.OfferDetailsPdfActivity.onCreate(OfferDetailsPdfActivity.java:58)
           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: can you show your logcat?

Comment: OnCreate method always called when your activity opens. Can you tell more about your issue?

Comment: How does your intent look? How do you know it is not being called?

Comment: I update my post. I add logcat

Comment: Why didn't your Activity start? Because of the error in your console `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null objects cannot be copied from Realm. E/AndroidRuntime(25281): at io.realm.Realm.checkValidObjectForDetach(Realm.java:1625)`

Comment: Is there anything here talking to a Realm instance?

Comment: No. The constructor  `presenter = new OfferDetailsPdfPresenterImplMvp(this, offerId);` pass offerId. But the `offerId =0` because method `onCreate()` is not call. And as result in class `com.myproject.android.customer.service.OfferService.getOffer(OfferService.java:54) throw exception Null objects cannot be copied from Realm.`

Comment: I update logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing the parent onCreate method without an offerId. Change the following two lines

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

to this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (savedInstanceState == null) { 
    super.onCreate(extras); 
}
```

Comment: No. The constructor `presenter = new OfferDetailsPdfPresenterImplMvp(this, offerId);`  pass offerId. But the offerId =0 because method onCreate() is not call. And as result in class `com.myproject.android.customer.service.OfferService.getOffer(OfferService.java:54) throw exception Null objects cannot be copied from Realm.`

Comment: I want to pass to presenter `offerId`. Is it correct to do this in method `createPresenter()`?

Comment: I've edited my answer once more, hopefully that helps.

Comment: Not help. `savedInstanceState` (because activity is create first time) is null and as result I get NPE.

Comment: You get NPE when trying to putInt into savedInstanceState? If that is the case, then just pass the extras bundle to super.onCreate(...)

Comment: Yes now it's work: `if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            super.onCreate(extras);
        }` . So this is a rule: If my activity has input params in extras, then I MUST call `super.onCreate(extras)`. This is how work Mosby ?

Comment: @Alex, Okay, I have edited my answer with the info from your comment above. I hope this answer helped solved the problem. Let me know if it helped. The parent activity needs the offerId in order to be created, that was the problem.

Comment: Yes, it help.Thanks

Comment: But why MvpActivity cere about extras? Extas content only incoming parameters,like offerId.

Comment: Because the MvpActivity class you are extending is MvpActivity<OfferDetailsPdfMvp.View, OfferDetailsPdfPresenterImplMvp>. So because of the <OfferDetailsPdfMvp.View, OfferDetailsPdfPresenterImplMvp> it will need offer information. Most likely because offerId is used by OfferDetailsPdfMvp or OfferDetailsPdfPresenterImplMvp objects.

Comment: `createPresenter()` is called from `onCreate()`. So you basically have to call super.onCreate() after you have read the bundle like this: `Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            offerId = extras.getInt(Offer.ID);
        }
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` - so this also work. Here source: https://github.com/sockeqwe/mosby/issues/285